# How to tell if $f(x,y)$, defined as $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$ when $x,y\neq0$ and $f(x,y) = 2$ when $x,y = (0,0)$, is continuous at $(0,0)$?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, functions, continuity

I have to decide if the following function is continuous at $(0,0)$.

$$f(x,y)= \begin{cases} 
      x^2+y^2 & x,y\neq 0 \\
      2 & x,y= (0,0)
   \end{cases}$$

so for the first one, I assume it is continuous, because there isn't a fraction, so there is no way for there to be an error when computing this (like dividing by a 0)

but for the second one, I am not sure where to go when all it gives me is the number 2 with the condition "if (x,y) = (0,0)

Comment: It's not "the first" or "the second" one, it's a single function!

Comment: oh, well then I am confused as to what to do with 2.

Comment: You check whether function has both left and right limits equal to the function value at that point.

Comment: Okay, so I plug the number 2 into the function?

Answer (score 2):

You aren't dealing with two functions, but a single function that is defined differently depending on the values of $x$ and $y$

$$f(x,y)= \begin{cases} 
      x^2+y^2 & x,y<> 0 \\
      2 & x,y= (0,0)
   \end{cases}
$$

So your job is to see if the function is continuous.

You want to look at the possible point of discontinuity at $(x,y)=(0,0)$.  What do you think about the function as it nears $(0,0)$?

Comment: I think that as it nears (0,0) it will still return a number, but they won't be the same number.
for example, (2,2) would return 8, but (1,1) would return 2

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: so I would just say that it is not continuous because they return different numbers?
what do I do with the bottom part of the function?

Comment: You would say it is not continuous because the limit of $f(x)$ as x or y approaches zero from either direction, does not in fact equal $f(x)$.  Because $0<>2$.  You can google "prove piecewise function continuous" for more info.